# How can labels/legends be added for all chart types in chart.js (chartjs.org)?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

The documentation for chart.js mentions "legend templates" but gives no resources or examples of such legends. How can these be displayed?

Comment: anyone can say like this but there is no options for this facility.

Comment: your question doesn't include any information what you have tried, what is working and where are the issues. Anyway, you can build  legend using unorder list with your information and style it as you want. Otherwise check [plugin](https://github.com/bebraw/Chart.js.legend) and other question about  chartjs here at SO

Answer (score 58):

You can include a legend template in the chart options:

```
//legendTemplate takes a template as a string, you can populate the template with values from your dataset 
var options = {
  legendTemplate : '<ul>'
                  +'<% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++) { %>'
                    +'<li>'
                    +'<span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].lineColor%>\"></span>'
                    +'<% if (datasets[i].label) { %><%= datasets[i].label %><% } %>'
                  +'</li>'
                +'<% } %>'
              +'</ul>'
  }

  //don't forget to pass options in when creating new Chart
  var lineChart = new Chart(element).Line(data, options);

  //then you just need to generate the legend
  var legend = lineChart.generateLegend();

  //and append it to your page somewhere
  $('#chart').append(legend);
```

You'll also need to add some basic css to get it looking ok.

Comment: Note that you'll need to change "lineColor" to whatever you're using; for example, in a Line Chart, you should use pointColor. You may also want to put something in the span, for example, the if statement.

Comment: FYI, the templating engine used is John Resig's micro templating - http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/ (from the Chart.js code comments)

Comment: And here's a web page that can help understand the syntax: https://www.npmjs.com/package/micro-template

Comment: I did this and for some reason I'm getting Uncaught ReferenceError: datasets is not defined

Comment: If you get datasets is not defined, you could be calling your chart before you are defining datasets. Call your "var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data, options);" for example, after you have declared dataSets.

Comment: If you prefer to avoid jQuery, use the `insertAdjacentHTML` method to add the legend: `container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', legendString)`

Answer (score 44):

1. The legend is part of the default options of the ChartJs library.  So you do not need to explicitly add it as an option.
2. The library generates the HTML.  It is merely a matter of adding that to the your page.  For example, add it to the innerHTML of a given DIV.  (Edit the default options if you are editing the colors, etc)

---

```
<div>
    <canvas id="chartDiv" height="400" width="600"></canvas>
    <div id="legendDiv"></div>
</div>

<script>
   var data = {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "The Flash's Speed",
                fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
            },
            {
                label: "Superman's Speed",
                fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
            }
        ]
    };

    var myLineChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chartDiv").getContext("2d")).Line(data);
    document.getElementById("legendDiv").innerHTML = myLineChart.generateLegend();
</script>
```

Comment: how to change the color?

Comment: not working for me! the backgroundcolor stays blank!

Comment: @PeterPiper The closing tag for span in legendTemplate option is misplaced, just move it to right before </li>

Answer (score 13):

Strangely, I didn't find anything about legends and labels in the Chart.js documentation. It seems like you can't do it with chart.js alone.

I used https://github.com/bebraw/Chart.js.legend which is extremely light, to generate the legends.

Comment: The 1.0 "beta" versions include the `generateLegend` method, but the two year old 0.2 "release" version does not.  This confused me for a while because cdnjs etc, only have the old 0.2 version.

Answer (score 4):

For line chart, I use the following codes.

First create custom style

```
.boxx{
    position: relative;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Then add this on your line options

```
var lineOptions = {
            legendTemplate : '<table>'
                            +'<% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++) { %>'
                            +'<tr><td><div class=\"boxx\" style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].fillColor %>\"></div></td>'
                            +'<% if (datasets[i].label) { %><td><%= datasets[i].label %></td><% } %></tr><tr height="5"></tr>'
                            +'<% } %>'
                            +'</table>',
            multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= datasetLabel %> - <%= value %>"

var ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext("2d");
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineData, lineOptions);
document.getElementById('legendDiv').innerHTML = myNewChart.generateLegend();
```

Don't forget to add

```
<div id="legendDiv"></div>
```

on your html where do you want to place your legend. That's it!

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old. But this might be useful for someone who is having the problem with legend. In addition to the answer given by ZaneDarken,
I modified the **chart.js** file to show the legend in my **pie chart**.
I changed the legendTemplate(which is declared many times for every chart type) just above these lines :

```js
Chart.Type.extend({
      //Passing in a name registers this chart in the Chart namespace
      name: "Doughnut",
      //Providing a defaults will also register the deafults in the chart namespace
      defaults: defaultConfig,
      .......
```

My legendTemplate is changed from

```html
legendTemplate : "
<ul class=\ "<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\">
  <% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%>
    <li><span style=\ "background-color:<%=datasets[i].strokeColor%>\"></span>
      <%if(datasets[i].label){%>
        <%=datasets[i].label%>
          <%}%>
    </li>
    <%}%>
</ul>"
```

To

```html
legendTemplate: "
<ul class=\ "<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\">
  <% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%>
    <li><span style=\ "-moz-border-radius:7px 7px 7px 7px; border-radius:7px 7px 7px 7px; margin-right:10px;width:15px;height:15px;display:inline-block;background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"> </span>
      <%if(segments[i].label){%>
        <%=s egments[i].label%>
          <%}%>
    </li>
    <%}%>
</ul>"
```